# Disable warning in VIM?

Tags: vim, perforce, warnings

Is there a way to disable warnings in VIM?

In particular, I want to disable Warning 12 when a file turns from read-only to writable. I have a script which opens the file for edit in perforce, but vim thinks the file has changed and issues a warning.

Thanks

Comment: Could it be that sometimes the file has actually changed? E.g. if you did not have the head revision open in VIM, an open for edit would actually try and replace your file with the latest one.

Comment: The command I'm using, 'p4 edit', won't sync to a different revision of that file, without explicitly telling it to.

The file would only be changed if I explicitly sync'd behind vim's back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add the following line to your .vimrc file :

set autoread

This will disable "read-only to writeable" warnings

Comment: Be aware this has an additional effect - to reread the file.  In OPs example this doesn't matter, but in some cases you may wish to only suppress the warning without rereading the buffer.  Autocmd for FileChangedRO and FileChangedShell can achieve this.

Answer (score 12):

I have the following in my .vimrc; you should only need the second one.  It echoes the message to the status bar instead of popping up a dialog.

```
autocmd FileChangedRO * echohl WarningMsg | echo "File changed RO." | echohl None
autocmd FileChangedShell * echohl WarningMsg | echo "File changed shell." | echohl None
```

Try `:help FileChangedShell` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using `FileChangedRO` for a while now to automatically checkout files when starting to edit them and found the W12 warning annoying as well. The problem is that p4 edit updates the file attributes to remove the read only flag. If as part of the initial edit you also change the file, Vim sees this as a conflict since it's no longer read only. Here's the solution I use which is a bit more conservative about using `FileChangedShell` in case the file was changed externally for some other reason.

```
let s:IgnoreChange=0
autocmd! FileChangedRO * nested
    \ let s:IgnoreChange=1 |
    \ call system("p4 edit " . expand("%")) |
    \ set noreadonly
autocmd! FileChangedShell *
    \ if 1 == s:IgnoreChange |
    \   let v:fcs_choice="" |
    \   let s:IgnoreChange=0 |
    \ else |
    \   let v:fcs_choice="ask" |
    \ endif
```

Comment: This is a beautiful solution, exactly what I was looking for, thanks!