# Can I disable or suppress Vim W11 Warnings?

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm using GVim (ver 7.3.46) - saving a text file to a network folder, I keep getting this W11 error, and as far as I know no other process / application is changing the file, I suspect vim thinks it changed because of lag to saving it to the network drive, and it detects a different timestamp? In any case, I'd like to suppress this error (and only this error) - is this possible?

```
W11: Warning: File "foo.txt" has changed since editing started
See ":help W11" for more info.
```

Comment: Have you read `:help W11`?

Comment: I did read `:help W11`. The help file indicates that:  

"The file which you have started editing has got another timestamp and the
contents changed (more precisely: When reading the file again with the current
option settings and autocommands you would end up with different text).  This
probably means that some other program changed the file." 

As I stated above, I wasn't aware of anything changing the file, hence why I was asking about options about turning off this warning. See below for my resolution on this and why just reading `W11` wasn't helping to resolve  this.

Comment: If you continue reading to the end of that paragraph: "... program changed the file. You will have to
find out what happened, and decide which version of the file you want to keep.
*Set the 'autoread' option if you want to do this automatically*." Anyway, I'm glad you solved it.

Comment: @mMontu Thanks. Yes, read the rest of that, too, but that description wasn't matching the behavior I was seeing -- as I said above, I wasn't aware of any changes and diff showed none, so the error made no sense in context, hence my desire at the time to disable it. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095708/disable-warning-in-vim) I just found today makes the same `:set autoread` recommendation, but also provides a way of only echoing an error to the status bar only: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1095804/853178

Comment: I'd still be curious to know if one can simply disable a certain warning entirely in Vim. 

Also, it's interesting that the question above was nearly the same question as mine (just referencing a different warning number) but got five upvotes instead of the downvote this received.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to further investigate the warnings instead of disable them. For instance, you mentioned that diff showed no differences, but this warning is also triggered if only the timestamp is changed, or if any of its permissions/attributes are changed, and these differences wouldn't be highlighted by diff. Suggestions on [Vim-FAQ 2-5](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5) could help to find the cause if it is triggered inside Vim. Them you could remove the undesired change to the file, or disable the warning only for that particular event.

Comment: I don't know why you got downvote, but note that this was not unanimous: you got two downvotes but one upvote. Maybe it was due to the question you mentioned - it shows up as the first result in a search for 'disable warning' in the vim questions of StackOverflow.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear about why you should avoid disable warnings. Vim tries to make the correct decisions; when it is not clear what should be done it prompts the user. On your example, setting `'autoread'`  means that you always want to use the contents that is on disk. While this is ok if it is just a matter of permissions/timestamp, it can be very disappointing if you spend a multiple hours editing a file, then a co-worker overwrites that file to correct a single character - your changes will be simple wiped out and replaced with your co-worker version.

Comment: Agree about the best scenario being that a person investigates the root cause, and is able to fix it. But what if they're not able to figure it out, or they don't have rights to change permissions, etc? No other editor was having problems with where I was saving files to -- as I said in the initial question it was a network destination, so my best theory is still that the timestamp was lagged enough that Vim was sensing *that* as the change to the file; unfortunately the error doesn't say.

Comment: If a person is unable to determine the cause of the error, should they just deal with the error messages forever? It seems odd to me that there would be no way to turn off error messages in situations where the person cannot determine what's causing them. Constant errors every time you save makes Vim basically unusable on that network location until you find a workaround or change the environment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When editing this file, set the `autoread` setting, so Vim will automatically reread it:

```
 :setl autoread
```

This can possibly be set via a modeline.

Another alternative is to set the `buftype` option for this file. But I am not sure, what other consequences this have, so I suspect this might have some side effects.

See

```
:h 'buftype'
```

For the possible values and their implications of the `buftype` option.

Comment: Thanks, Christian, I added:
    set: autoread to my .gvimrc, as well as my below information.

Answer (score 8):

Between Christian's suggestion of

```
:set autoread
```

being added to my .gvimrc, as well as storing the backup and swap file local

```
:set backupdir=~/backup
:set directory=~/backup
```

seems to have resolved my issue.